# Inversifyjs: passing container to another object causes binding resolution to fail

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I have the following:

```
//Editor.TS
let values = await Promise.all([Theme.getTheme(config.theme), I18n.getI18n(config.i18n)]);

//Set up DI container
this.services = new Container();
decorate(injectable(), EventEmitter);
this.services.bind<IContext>(TYPES.Context).toConstantValue(this);
this.services.bind<Theme>(TYPES.Theme).toConstantValue(values[0]);
this.services.bind<I18n>(TYPES.I18n).toConstantValue(values[1]);
this.services.bind<any>(TYPES.Data).toConstantValue(data);
this.services.bind<Toolbox>(TYPES.Toolbox).to(Toolbox).inSingletonScope();
this.services.bind<Workspace>(TYPES.Workspace).to(Workspace).inSingletonScope();
```

A call to `this.services.get<I18n>(TYPES.I18n);` works perfefctly if it's in the same function as the code above. However, I have a plugin system where each plugin is built (with webpack) into it's own library. The idea is you pull in only the plugins you need so as not to bloat the core library with stuff people might never use.

Anyways so the plugin constructor looks like this:

```
//APlugin.ts
constructor(config, services: Container) {
    this.currentLang = this.defaultLang = config.defaultLanguage;
    this.supportedLangs = config.supportedLanguages;

    this.i18n = services.get<I18n>(TYPES.I18n);
    this.context = services.get<IContext>(TYPES.Context);

    //Editor Events
    this.context.on("dataGenerating", e => this.onDataGenerating());
    this.context.on("dataGenerated", data => this.onDataGenerated(data));

}
```

As you can see, the plugin accepts an anonymous object and a `Container` instance. The idea here is to allow the plugin designer to pull any dependencies they need from the container. Writing the dependencies directly in the constructor is not an option for reasons that i'd rather not go into.

The plugins are instantiated as follows:

```
//Editor.ts
loadPlugin(plugin): IEditorPlugin {
    let instance;

    if (Array.isArray(plugin))
        instance = new plugin[0](plugin[1], this.services);
    else
        instance = new plugin[0](this.services);

    this.plugins.push(instance);

    if (typeof instance.getMenuDom === 'function')
        this.workspace.addButton(instance.getMenuDom());

    return instance;
}
```

Here, the `plugin` parameter can be either a `constructor` or `[constructor, config: any]`

So the issue is that when the plugin's constructor is running I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: No matching bindings found for
>   serviceIdentifier: Symbol(I18n)

Remember that the *exact* same call to `get`, only in the same function as the `container` is defined works just fine.

If I debug and break on `this.i18n = services.get<I18n>(TYPES.I18n);` in APlugin.ts, I see:
[image]

So it looks like the `container` is set up and working correctly, the `_bindingDictionary` property contains a reference to `TYPES.I18n`. I should also mention that this issue occurs with *all* bindings. Replacing the `get<I18n>` with any other bound type generates the same error.

I did some digging and it appears the point of failure is in the `getBindings` function:
[image]
[image]

The call to `bindingDictionary.hasKey` fails even though it's clear that the result should be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because calling `Symbol(..)` creates a unique symbol *every time it is called* regardless of the argument being the same or not.

The key was to use `Symbol.for(..)`. This creates a symbol and stores it in the global symbol cache, or return that symbol if it already exists. This will survive across contexts.

Comment: Thank you! Been fighting this for the last 8 hours and this was exactly it.
I ran into this when using hot reload.